# Prove that there are exactly two solutions to the equation $x^3 = x^2$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-verification, proof-writing

This is Velleman's exercise 3.6.12.c:

Prove that there are **exactly two** solutions to the equation $x^3 = x^2$.

Here's my proof of it:

Proof.

Existence. Let $x = 0$ then clearly $x^3 = x^2$ and let $x = 1$ then clearly $x^3 = x^2$.

Uniqueness. We choose an arbitrary $z$ such that $z^3 = z^2$. Now we consider two exhaustive cases:

Case 1. $z = 0 = x$, then clearly $0 = 0$.

Case 2. $z \neq 0$, then $z^2 \neq 0$ and dividing the equation $z^3 = z^2$ by $z^2$, we get $z = 1 = x$.

Is my proof correct?

Thanks.

Comment: $x^3=x^2$  means $x^2(x-1)=0$, so...

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi So we have three solutions: $0$, $1$, and $\epsilon$ where $\epsilon^2 = 0$...

Comment: Please be more precise, do you mean exactly two solutions **in** $\bf \Bbb C\!$ ? (it can have more than two solutions in some rings, so such precision is necessary).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct.

But here's a more standard proof . .  .

\begin{align*}
&x^3=x^2\\[4pt]
\iff\;&x^3-x^2=0\\[4pt]
\iff\;&x^2(x-1)=0\\[4pt]
\iff\;&x^2=0\;\;\text{or}\;\;x-1=0\\[4pt]
\iff\;&x=0\;\;\text{or}\;\;x=1\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I know that but since I'm studying mathematical logic by Velleman (it's the way he does proofs), it is actually preferred to be that kind of verbose.

Comment: Which is why, in my opinion, that book should be avoided. Nevertheless, if you can live with playing the game using Velleman's style, cool, but don't let it "burn in".

Comment: Could you please recommend a better substitute then?

Comment: My recommendation is to learn logic and proofs from actual math books (e.g., elementary texts in$\;(1)\;$Discrete Math$\;(2)\;$Number Theory$\;(3)\;$Modern Algebra).

Comment: @Heptapod  The book is actually highly regarded. So as quasi has admitted his statement is in his opinion.  Learning proofs and logic along with more basic courses, gives you a huge advantage in later math classes.  To learn only the logic required in a specific context, and another specific context doesn't grow your aptitude for flexible thinking, reasoning, across all specific contexts.

Comment: @quasi Have you taught with the book in question, or have you read it from cover to cover?  It appears that you have not.

Comment: I rejected it many years ago.

Comment: It is already clear that you "rejected it."  But you haven't answered my question, @quasi.

Comment: It means I read it to the point where I felt it was more detrimental than beneficial.

Comment: NAN... and certainly not fully informed.  You're entitled to have ***opinions***, but you should avoid dissing a text, or institution, of a person, or a method, when you answer questions.  If you feel compelled to answer, answer the asker's question. (period)  if you have an opinion, say so in a comment **only if asked for it**  on the text being studied.  And admit it is your opinion, and, in this case, that you may have very well rejected it in the first chapter, perhaps even the intro, given your avoidance of my question, and have not read the text in full.

Answer (score 0):

Prove that there are exactly two solutions to the equation $x^3=x^2$

Here's two alternate approaches to this problem:

1)

We can use a graphing calculator or computer program to plot the functions $y=x^3$ and $y=x^2$ as individual functions. Provided that we adjust the viewing window correctly, we can see that there are exactly two intersections between these two graphs. Which implies that there are 2 values for $x$ that satisfy the original equation $x^3=x^2$

2) (if we were asked this problem in a calculus class)

We can move all the $x$ terms to one side of the equations, resulting in the following: $0=x^3 - x^2$. We could then use the intermediate value theorem, to prove that there are two roots to the equation $0=x^3 - x^2$.

*Note* that this particular approach is slightly more cumbersome, as we would have to determine two intervals on which the IVT can be applied to prove the existence of a root. That said, this would prove nonetheless that exactly two solutions exist for $x^3=x^2$

Solving this algebraically is clearly the most efficient means to a solution, but in spirit of making things more complex than they need to be, I thought I'd share these alternate approaches for anyone who may be struggling to recognize the algebraic solution to this problem.